# Can I say "Since we met, I had been meaning to say that I like everything you do"?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, sentence, past-participles, context

Hypothetically, I said *"I like everything you do"* in the past.

So now can I say *"Since we met, I had been meaning to say that I like everything you do." ?*

Is it okay to use past perfect continuous in this context ?

Because I wanted to say that over the past two months and I already said it.

Comment: If you've already said _X_, then it wouldn't make sense to say _I had been meaning to say X_ now.

Comment: Are you trying to say, “I had been meaning to say that I like everything you do ever since we first met. I can’t believe it took me over two months to actually say it. “

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The present participle is preferable in your exemplar.

> Since we met, I have been meaning to say I like everything you do.
> [Notice I omitted *that* between *say* and *I like*.]

To use the past participle (viz., *had been meaning to say*) is to say you did [past tense] like everything he or she did, but now--well, not so much!

The past participle implies the following:

> Since we met, I had been meaning to say I like everything you do, but
> now I am not so sure. [In other words, I do *not* like everything you do. In fact, your being late for our get-togethers annoys me.]

Comment: Agreed. Another aspect is that *Since we met* sets the reader up for something coming after that moment. But *had been meaning* places that period before something, although there's no such thing.